# Cannot read property 'expectGET' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is my code and I get the following error and can't figure it out.

```
describe('Myctrl', function() {

   var $httpBackend, scope, createController, authRequestHandler;

   // Set up the module  
   beforeEach(module('myApp'));

      alert("Hello there!");
    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
     // Set up the mock http service responses
 alert("Hello there!");
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

     // backend definition common for all tests
 alert("Hello there!");
     authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php')
                            .respond(true);

     // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)

     $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'); 

     // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
     var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');


     createController = function() {

       return $controller('Myctrl', {'$scope' : scope});

     };

   })

);

/*
  afterEach(function() {

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();

     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();


   });*/

   it('should fetch authentication token', function() {

       //create expectation 
     $httpBackend.expectGET('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php');

     var controller = createController()
     $httpBackend.flush();
     expect(scope.names).toBeTruthy(true); 



   });


});
```

I tried some different things but I still can't figure out what is wrong. It seems like there's nothing wrong. What would be the solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored a bit your code. However I'm not sure if the problem is with it. I think that you also might have NOT included the ngMock (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) and that's why you're getting such error

```
describe('Myctrl', function () {

  var $httpBackend, $scope, createController;

  // Set up the module  
  beforeEach(module('myApp', ['ngMock']));

  beforeEach(inject(['$httpBackend', '$rootScope', '$controller', function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    // Set up the mock http service responses
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    // backend definition common for all tests
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php').respond(function () {
      return [200, true];
    });

    // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope) 
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    createController = function () {
      return $controller('Myctrl', { '$scope': $scope });
    };
  }]));


  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should fetch authentication token', function () {
    //create expectation 
    $httpBackend.expectGET('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php');
    var controller = createController();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect($scope.names).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Comment: i added the angular js and angular-mock.js but still the error is the same\

Comment: How do include the ngMock module? 
Probably replacing **beforeEach(module('myApp'));** with **beforeEach(module('myApp', ['ngMock']));** would work. I'll modify my post with it

Comment: this is not working i tried it but still i get the errors

Answer (score 0):

first we have to declare fake back end for using $htttp service in jasmine .

```
describe("Test Add Category JSON",function(){
      'use strict';
      var scope, ctrl , $httpBackend;
      beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope){
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
       ctrl = $controller('View1Ctrl',{$scope:scope});

     }));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_){
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
     }));

      it('Test Load JSON Name',function(){

        $httpBackend.whenGET('../json/login/getCategory.json').respond({

          "categoryID": 1,
          "coreIndustry": "Prime Video",
          "subIndustry": "Prime Video",
          "classification12": "Easy"
        })
        scope.loadJson();
         $httpBackend.flush();
         expect(scope.data.categoryID).toEqual(1);


      });

    });
```